# Unable to filter out list having nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My json structure looks like something like this

```
products = [{
    id: ...
    name: ...
    attributes: [{
       name: 'color',
       attribute_values: [{ value: 'blue' }, { value: 'green' }]
    }]
}]
```

I have `filteredColors` which I'm getting from query params which is an array of colors like `['blue', 'green', ...]`

I'm trying to filter my products list based on the `filteredColors`.
I tried something like this

```
const handleFilterColors = (product) => {
    return filteredColors.length > 0 ? filteredColors.includes(
        product.attributes.map((attribute) => {
            return attribute.attribute_values.map((value) => value.value)
    })) : true;
}

const filteredAndSortedProducts = products.filter(handleFilterColors)
```

But this is not working. Need some help in filtering out here.

Comment: So you want to keep the products containing at least one attribute containing a valid color ? And you want to return the full product, without filtering the non valid colors ?

Comment: yup that's the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `product.attributes.map` and `attribute.attribute_values.map`, both will return arrays and you're passing that array to includes, that will always return false.

You need to update the code to use `some`

```
const handleFilterColors = (product) => {
return filteredColors.length > 0
    ? product.attributes.some((attribute) =>
          attribute.attribute_values.some((value) =>
              filteredColors.includes(value.value)
          )
      )
    : true; };
```

Comment: yes, got what mistake i was doing. Thanks for the resolution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to only return true for products that have at least one of the colors in the `filteredColors`
array You can do this by using the `some()` method.

```js
const products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Product 1",
  attributes: [{
      name: "color",
      attribute_values: [{
          value: "blue"
      }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Product 2",
  attributes: [{
      name: "color",
      attribute_values: [{
          value: "green"
      }]
  }]
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Product 3",
  attributes: [{
      name: "color",
      attribute_values: [{
          value: "red"
      }]
  }]
}];
const handleFilterColors = (product) => {
  return filteredColors.some(color => {
      return product.attributes.some(attribute => {
          return attribute.attribute_values.some(value => {
              return value.value === color;
          });
      });
  });
}

const filteredColors = ["blue", "green"];

const filteredAndSortedProducts = products.filter(handleFilterColors);

console.log(filteredAndSortedProducts);
```